# How to reload div element from remote file using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

index.php

```
<div class="container" id="content">
<?php print $rs['current_number']; ?>
</div>
```

declarator.php

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          $('#reloader').click(function() {
            var self = window.location.href;
            console.log("Loading '#content' from " + self);
            //$('#content').load(self + ' #content');
            $('#content').load('index.php #content');
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<button id="reloader" type="button"> UPDATE NUMBER </button>
```

I want to refresh the div element from index.php using button from declarator.php

P.S

I dont want to use intervals, I know  it can be dome by interval but the points is I want to load the element after I click the button from declarator page.

Comment: $('#content').load(... will try to load data into an element with the ID "content" in your page, but I don't see any such element in the HTML of declarator.php that you have shown us. Is that the issue? You told us your intention but didn't explain what difficulty or error you're having with the current code?

Comment: Also, `index.php #content` is wrong - URLs don't have spaces in them like that, and the server won't see anything after the # anyway, that does not get sent in the http request

Comment: You can use this to send some additional data along : $.get( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );

Comment: Hello, I want to load the div id=content in index.php upon clicking the button in declarator.php. The content of the div is from database.

Comment: You _might_ be interested in a library called unpoly: https://unpoly.com/

Comment: @ADyson _"Also, index.php #content is wrong - URLs don't have spaces in them like that"_ - true, but this is jQuery's own specific "syntax" for loading page fragments, see https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments: _"If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded."_ [...]

Comment: [...] And since it can be other selectors besides an ID selector as well, the space is necessary - with an ID selector, `index.php#foobar` would of course also work, but switch that to a class and make that URL `index.php.foobar` instead, and the server would likely respond with a 404.

Comment: @ArisEspiritu you still need to load the content _into_ something and that the moment your declarator page doesn't seem to have a "content" element to load the remote file into